# My question was closed, and I edited it. How do I get it reviewed to reopen?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How do I get my question reviewed for possible reopening?

[Lookup Table architectures guidance for taxonomy mapping](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36392/lookup-table-architectures-guidance-for-taxonomy-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this question is mostly about programming and is not focused on the computational science aspect. Consider reading through [on-topic of Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and, if it is applicable, edit your question so that it is on-topic.

What else can be done:

1. Posting on Meta (which you already did) with a justification why this question is good and on-topic (in my opinion, it better be done on the question itself).
2. Add relevant tags to the question. Currently, it features only the programming language tag [python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), such questions are rarely on-topic on Computational Science.
3. Consider migrating question to a more appropriate community if you believe it is more suited there. For that, flag for moderator and indicate your intentions in the flag notes.
4. The first edit on the question will move it into the reopen queue, where the reviewers will decide whether it should be reopened. **Currently, your question is in the review queue.**

The advice I have given is pretty general, and not necessarily specific to your question in particular.

Comment: I did read the on-topic as I was considering posting my question in data science stack, and they suggested I post elsewhere. Then I read the on-topic as relating to more classic problems of computer science and the packages which might apply to these goals. After the rejection, I stripped out the package request, and thought to make it strictly about solving the problem of managing LUT tables. I don’t have a computer science education. Maybe that’s why I’m not understanding, or clued into the types of general computer problems which people want to answer in this stack.

Comment: @xtian notice, there are two communities here: [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and Computational Science SE. I assume, there is confusion about it.